# Whatsapp sharing button for blogspot blogger without javascript

Tags: share, blogger, whatsapp

I am trying to add following code in blogger temlate (blogger.com). but failed

```
<a expr:href='&quot;whatsapp://send?text=&quot;data:post.title - data:post.canonicalUrl&quot;'>Share of Whatsapp</a>
```

I want to make like this for whatsapp sharing without using any script.

e.g.

```
<a href='whatsapp://send?text=Google - http://www.google.com'>Share of Whatsapp</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="Take a look at this awesome website:" data-href=" ( your url )">Share</a>
```

Comment: not working, I think your code need a script [link](https://github.com/kriskbx/whatsapp-sharing/releases), but I want to avoid extra javascript.

Comment: :| ,or include the js or die '-'

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript it would be a lot easier, because the parameters need to be url encoded. You could use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode your strings.

If you still don't want to use JavaScript, there are plenty of free [urlencoder](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=urlencode+online) online.

So if you want to share your problem for this page it should look like this:

```
Help me with my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252484/whatsapp-sharing-button-for-blogspot-blogger-without-javascript


<a href='whatsapp://send?text=Help%20me%20with%20my%20problem%20http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F30252484%2Fwhatsapp-sharing-button-for-blogspot-blogger-without-javascript'>Share the problem</a>
```